# ADAL .NET to ADFS

Tags: .net, adfs, adal

I am trying to do exactly what this library is designed to do: allow my .NET code (currently a test console app) to retrieve a token from ADFS for the current user, and use the token to authenticate with and call a REST Web API endpoint. [This article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/09/12/active-directory-authentication-library-adal-v1-for-net-general-availability/) calls it the basic flow supported by ADAL.  My organisation run Windows Server 2012 SP2 ADFS.  The console app and ADFS are on-premise.

Can anyone point me to a full example of how to set this up and use it?  The code snippets are fine, but there's a lot around it that's not explained - like what is the Authentication Context endpoint?  What do I ask my sysadmins for?  They have given me an STS endpoint, but that does not seem to work.  I think I need more than just a server URL, probably need to be passed a query string or other extension, but I can't find any explanation around that.  Virtually all the samples and examples I have found deal with registering the Client app with Azure, and I am not using Azure.

My code currently looks like this:

```
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://sts.myorg.co.za");
var token = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("http://myservices/service1", "a8cb2a71-da38-4cf4-9023-7799d00e09f6", new Uri("http://TodoListClient"));
```

but the call to AquireToken fails with an exception saying `This method overload is not supported by 'https://sts.myorg.co.za'`.

Any help or pointers appreciated!

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You should pass validateAuthority=false to the constructor of ADAL.

Comment: Thanks, I see from [the documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/ADAL-.NET-Q-&-A) that this is needed for ADFS, which doesn't support authority validation.  Are you able to help with other ADFS-specific questions please?  All [the examples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop) have Azure-specific instructions such as getting and using a client id for my app.  How does one do that with ADFS?  Or is the procedure different, and if so, where can I find documentation or an example?  Thanks!